# Weird behaviour of an array of dictionaries

Tags: python

I wanted to have an array of dictionaries, such that length of the array was 3.
So, I did

```
X = [{}] * 3
```

Now I wanted to populate first of these dictionaries. So, I did:

```
X[0]['hi'] = 'hello'
```

Now, if I print X, I was expecting to see:

```
[{'hi': 'hello'}, {}, {}]
```

but to my horror, what I saw was:

```
[{'hi': 'hello'}, {'hi': 'hello'}, {'hi': 'hello'}]
```

Clearly, the three dictionaries are the same. Can someone tell me why python made this design choice? Also, is there a way, other than explicit iteration, to initialise the array with empty dicts?

Comment: use X = [{} for i in xrange(3)]

Comment: @user2393267 typically `for _`, to indicate that you aren't using the loop variable

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you are right.